# Swift Mutable Array in C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to access a property of a Swift class using pure C code, since I'm in the Audio Thread.

The property is declared so:

```
var Triggers: [[Int]] = [[Int]]()
```

C sees this as a `NSArray` (non mutable) hence I can't modify its elements. Declaring the property as a `NSMutableArray` is also not helping.

What would be the correct approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to pass your array to C function then the easiest way is to pass pointer argument using the & operator like so

```
your_c_func(arg1, arg2, &Triggers);
```

If you have to do something more advanced then you will have to play with UnsafeBufferPointers and it's friends.

Here's some links to get you started on this:

[Apple's Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6)

[Unsafe Swift by Russ Bishop](https://realm.io/news/russ-bishop-unsafe-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

I will say, that I have little experience with Objective-C Interop. But personally I would assign the contents of the immutable array to an `NSMutableArray`, and then perform modifications on the copy - if needed of course.

Comment: I'd need to modify the object's property. I won't be able to put the NSMutableArray back in the object